# PDF to Webpage Copy-Paste activity :: Process Automation

Tags: selenium, pdf, automation

Help me choose a way through which I can achieve the following.The steps to be performed are listed below.

Steps

---

1)Open a PDF file .Copy the value of each cell one by one.Please find image of sample PDF file
[image]
2)Open browser URL https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1MWbMjCHgBUylLWo2fWeyZnoUsx33ewQ0S39_ykbWwYc/viewform and then paste the corresponding value of PDF in a webpage form.

3) After repeating the above process for all fields in PDF file,there is a 'Submit' button in the webpage form which needs to clicked upon.

The above steps need to be performed on all the PDF files under a folder.

Can Selenium be used for this task or some other automation tools??

If selenium can be used, request to brief the process.

Regards,
Sri

Comment: Yes i guess it can be done via Selenium +java ,can you plz share a pdf sample so that i can try and share the working sample

Comment: The link for the sample file https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7NgTayxCMOTdl83VEdLNkt3SDg

Comment: hi can you confirm format of all the pdf will be same or different

Comment: hi raj...the format would be fixed...the same format for all pdf files..